# Flatten list of dynamic objects in c#

Tags: linq

I have a list of dynamics:

```
var list = new List<dynamic> { Json.Decode(@"{""no"":""001"",""photos"":[""01.jpg"",""02.jpg""]}"), Json.Decode(@"{""no"":""002"",""photos"":[""01.jpg""]}") };
```

How can i use selectMany to fatten the photos property into:

```
{"no": "001", "photo": "01.jpg"}
{"no": "001", "photo": "02.jpg"}
{"no": "002", "photo": "01.jpg"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe you want to get flatten list of photos

```
var photos = list.SelectMany(x=>(DynamicJsonArray)x.photos).Cast<string>();
```

Output

[image]